# Azure bat file to start VPS stops at cmd after nodevars.bat

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Good afternoon.

I am flumuxed because this seems straight forward. I want to bat some simple tasks such as starting an azure VPS but the bat file stops at the cmd prompt after running nodevars.bat. Ie the batch file does not continue and sits awaiting further instructions

I'm sure the answer is simple and for some reason I can't find anyone else who's having the same problem.

Script is simple (and it is run from my local machine):

```
cmd /k "C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat"

azure vm start VPSName

timeout /t 300

cls

REM VPSName should have started by now

C:\VPS\VPSName.RDP
```

This is the output (it doesn't continue on and start the VM):

```
C:\VPS>cmd /k "C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat"
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.4 (x64) and npm.

C:\VPS>
```

Comment: I think you'll find the use of /k is the cause. That option "Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt. This is useful for testing, to examine variables." src: http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html. Can't you simply just call that batch file directly rather than invoking with CMD?

Comment: Thank you Simon for your suggestions. I have tried all sorts of variations including with and without the /k and /c switches, with and without cmd. I have tried calling the file directly.  The one that gets me closest to working is if I add a timeout after the nodevars.bat (as per the ss64 instructions /k causes the next command to run right away).  With timeout it runs the subsequent commands however it does not recognise the azure command. Presumably because that was run in a separate cmd window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bat is working. You start a new cmd program, add the variables to that cmd process, then keep running. When you exit those changes will be thrown away and the rest of your bat file will run.

Use the `call` command.

## Starting a Program

See start /? and call /? for help on all three ways.

### Specify a program name

```
c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

In a batch file the batch will wait for the program to exit. When
typed the command prompt does not wait for graphical
programs to exit.

If the program is a batch file control is transferred and the rest of the calling batch file is not executed.

### Use Start command

```
start "" c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

Start starts a program and does not wait. Console programs start in a new window. Using the /b switch forces console programs into the same window, which negates the main purpose of Start.

Start uses the Windows graphical shell - same as typing in WinKey + R (Run dialog). Try

```
start shell:cache
```

### Use Call command

Call is used to start batch files and wait for them to exit and continue the current batch file.

### .

Comment: thank you user5032396, that resolved the issue.  Appreciate your taking the time.